# image_tag not displaying image in aws beanstalk production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an image tag to display my avatar.  The tag works in development mode but not in the production mode when i deploy it to aws beanstalk. The place where I view the avatar picture shows up as "img 0645" Its almost as if the image gets saved but is displaying the img name in a way or id. The image itself isn't showing up!! How do i make the image show up??? Thanks!!!

**Im using**

Postgres, puma, aws beanstalk, ruby on rails

[image: image_tag display in production mode]

Not sure if this helps but I used Find to lookup anything in the log with avatar in the search and came up with these.

```
"GET /system/users/avatars/000/000/001/thumb/IMG_0645.JPG?1465126426 HTTP/1.1" 404 1564
"GET /system/users/avatars/000/000/001/medium/IMG_0645.JPG?1465126426 HTTP/1.1" 404 1564
```

**Production.rb**

```rails
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both threaded web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Enable Rack::Cache to put a simple HTTP cache in front of your application
  # Add `rack-cache` to your Gemfile before enabling this.
  # For large-scale production use, consider using a caching reverse proxy like
  # NGINX, varnish or squid.
  # config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = true

  # Disable serving static files from the `/public` folder by default since
  # Apache or NGINX already handles this.
  config.serve_static_files = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = false

  # Asset digests allow you to set far-future HTTP expiration dates on all assets,
  # yet still be able to expire them through the digest params.
  config.assets.digest = true

  # `config.assets.precompile` and `config.assets.version` have moved to config/initializers/assets.rb

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Sendfile' # for Apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for NGINX

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # Use the lowest log level to ensure availability of diagnostic information
  # when problems arise.
  config.log_level = :debug

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  # config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = 'http://assets.example.com'

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation cannot be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  # Do not dump schema after migrations.
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false

#allow pictures
  config.serve_static_assets = false


#for rails devise
  Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = 'http://essayfriends-env.ss8bhfhxct.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com'
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8"




end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your `config/environments/production.rb`

`config.serve_static_assets = false`

Comment: Hey David!! I tried your code and re-deployed then restarted the server. But still no use.  Could another config from the production.rb file be conflicting with that statement??

Comment: @MichaelLombardo you do have another line setting this variable in your `production.rb` - `config.serve_static_files = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?`.  You could try commenting this out.  The underlying issue is probably getting nginx to serve your static files for you rather than the default rails server, so if the problem isn't here, it might be your ngnix setup.

Comment: Im not really sure how to setup ngnix!! i only made a folder called .ebextensions and added a file called 01_files.config and that i cant get to work either about increasing file_body_size. I tried commenting that out and it didnt wind up working :/ must be the nginx setup.. i just dont know how.

Comment: A lot of things to try here https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=150904

Comment: i changed the config.serve_static_assets = true.. I can see pictures now however when i check the code in browser it seems to not save to s3 but instead on my public folder of the rails application which is not good! Im starting to consider moving to heroku until aws fixes this service!!! :). I dont really know how to access the ngnix files to see whats inside or where to find them.. Not sure if i find them in aws service site or in my rails app.  I know you set commands for your server through the app but i dont know how to view the changes in beanstalk. or access them in beanstalk to view!!